# S3 Requester Pays setting disabled for single ARN via the policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 Bucket with the Requester Pays setting enabled, for a single user ARN or role I would like to disable this setting via the S3 policy is it possible to do this? I don't want to disable the Requester Pays setting for any other objects or users, just for a single user/role. I also do not want to store duplicate data in a second bucket.

Ideally I'm looking for something like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "DisableRequestorPays",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::123:user/data",
            "arn:aws:iam::123:role/data"
        ]
    },
    "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
            "aws:RequesterPays":"false"
        }
    },
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket"
}
```

Comment: `for a single ARN` by this do you mean a _single object_ in the bucket? A set of objects, or something else? Can you give an example?

Comment: @sytech Sorry I'll clarify that above

Comment: Got it. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, requestor pays settings apply to the entire bucket. You cannot apply the setting conditionally to individual objects or specific users/requestors. Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RequesterPaysExamples.html):

> You can set Requester Pays only at the bucket level. You can't set Requester Pays for specific objects within the bucket.

If you don't want the requestor to pay for certain objects, those objects will need to be stored in a different bucket that does not have a requestor pays policy applied.

---

A possible workaround may be to allow the specified user/role to [assume a cross-account role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) that resides in the bucket owner's account. That way, the user/role can access the bucket, but use the owner's account to pay for the request.

For example:

1. Create an IAM role in the bucket owner's account (your account).
2. You give the `data` user principal from another account access to assume the role you created.
3. The `data` user uses the assume-role operation to obtain credentials for the role in the bucket owner's account and use those credentials to access the S3 bucket
4. The bucket owner account, not the `data` user principal's account, will be charged for the request

Comment: Can I create a cross-account role for an external account?

Comment: @pyCthon yes, you can allow external accounts to assume a role in your account (where the bucket resides). You just need to setup the trust document to trust the origin account/principal. See also [Providing access to AWS accounts owned by third parties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_third-party.html).